# Why is this save function working on a local project but not on the server and cpanel?

Tags: laravel

I'm migrating a project that was a localhost to a server that has cpanel on it, the project is there and mostly is working as expected. Except for the importation funcionality, for some reason the numbers are being weird.

This is the function

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
    $products = $request->all();
    $countries = ['COSTA RICA', 'NICARAGUA', 'HONDURAS'];
    try {
        DB::beginTransaction();
        foreach ($products as $product) {
            Log::info($product);

            $dbProduct = $this->getProduct($product['SKU']);
//          Log::error($dbProduct);
            $dbProduct->code = $product['CODIGO'];
            $dbProduct->sku = $product['SKU'];
            $dbProduct->description_spanish = $product['DESCRIPCION - ESPAÑOL'];
            $dbProduct->description_english = $product['DESCRIPCION - INGLES'];
            $dbProduct->image = 'img/products/' . $product['SKU'] . '.jpg';
            $dbProduct->discount = $product['DESCUENTO'];
            $dbProduct->cif = $product['FOB'];
            $dbProduct->color = (isset($product['COLOR'])) ? ($product['COLOR']) : '';
            $dbProduct->color_ab = (isset($product['COLOR-AB'])) ? ($product['COLOR-AB']) : '';

            $this->isSet('PROVEEDOR', $product);
            $provider = $this->getProvider($product['PROVEEDOR']);
            $this->isSet('MARCA', $product);
            $brand = $this->getBrand($product['MARCA'], $provider->id);
            $dbProduct->brand_id = $brand->id;
            $dbProduct->save();
            $dbProduct->tags()->detach();


            if (isset($product['ETIQUETAS DE RELACION'])) {
                foreach (explode(',', str_replace(' ', '', $product['ETIQUETAS DE RELACION'])) as $etiqueta) {
                    $tag = $this->getTag($etiqueta);
//                  Log::error($tag);
                    $dbProduct->tags()->attach($tag->id);
                }
                }


            foreach ($countries as $country) {
                $c = $this->getCountry($country);
                if (isset($product["FI $country"]) && isset($product["Margen $country"])) {

                    $fi = $product["FI $country"];
                    $margin = $product["Margen $country"];
                    $factor = $this->getExportationFactor($c->id, $dbProduct->id, $margin, $fi);
                    Log::info('new factor '.$factor);
                    Log::info('fi '. $product["FI $country"]);
                    Log::info('margen '. $product["Margen $country"]);
                }
                if (isset($product["PRECIO $country"])) {
                   $price = $this->getCountryProduct($c->id, $dbProduct->id, $product["PRECIO $country"]);
                    Log::info('price '.$price);
                    Log::info('price: '. $product["PRECIO $country"]);
                }
            }

            $sizes = $this->filterArray($product, "Talla");
            $dbProduct->sizes()->detach();
            foreach ($sizes as $key => $value) {
                $size = $this->getSize($key);
                $dbProduct->sizes()->attach($size->id);
            }

            $dbProduct->fields()->detach();

            $tables = $this->filterArray($product, "tabla");
            $this->fillProductField($tables, $dbProduct->id, 'table');


            $lists = $this->filterArray($product, "lista");
            $this->fillProductField($lists, $dbProduct->id, 'list');

        }
        DB::commit();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        DB::rollBack();
        throw new HttpException(500, 'Sucedio un error importando la información favor intentar de nuevo');
    }

}
```

this is the output for the local project

```
local.INFO: array (
  'CODIGO' => '62NBB',
  'SKU' => '62NBB',
  'ETIQUETAS DE RELACION' => 'Casco, Standard Series, Almohadilla, Ventilación, Ratchet',
  'PROVEEDOR' => 'Bullard',
  'DESCRIPCION - ESPAÑOL' => 'Casco, Estilo Standard Series con ventilación, Con almohadilla de vinilo, Suspensión Ratchet de 4 puntos, Talla única, Color Azul Navy',
  'DESCRIPCION - INGLES' => '4pt, Ratchet Vinyl Brow Pad, Standard Series Vented Cap Style, Navy Blue',
  'DESCUENTO' => 0.07,
  'COLOR-AB' => 'NB',
  'COLOR' => 'NAVY BLUE',
  'MARCA' => 'Bullard',
  'FOB' => 8.54,
  'FI COSTA RICA' => 0.85,
  'Margen COSTA RICA' => 0.65,
  'FI NICARAGUA' => 0.82,
  'Margen NICARAGUA' => 0.65,
  'FI HONDURAS' => 0.75,
  'Margen HONDURAS' => 0.65,
  'Costo CR' => 10.047058823529412,
  'Costo Nic' => 10.414634146341463,
  'Costo Hn' => 11.386666666666665,
  'PRECIO COSTA RICA' => 15.457013574660632,
  'PRECIO NICARAGUA' => 16.02251407129456,
  'PRECIO HONDURAS' => 17.517948717948716,
  'lista-Detalles de compra -Detalle 1' => 'Unidad del precio: ea.',
  'lista-Detalles de compra -Detalle 2' => 'Minimo de compra 20',
  'lista-Detalles de compra -Detalle 3' => 'Cantidad por caja 20',
)  
local.INFO: new factor {"country_id":1,"product_id":415,"margin":0.65,"fi":0.85,"id":1237}  
local.INFO: fi 0.85  
local.INFO: margen 0.65  
local.INFO: price {"country_id":1,"product_id":415,"price":15.457013574660632,"id":1235}  
local.INFO: price: 15.457013574661  
local.INFO: new factor {"country_id":2,"product_id":415,"margin":0.65,"fi":0.82,"id":1238}  
local.INFO: fi 0.82  
local.INFO: margen 0.65  
local.INFO: price {"country_id":2,"product_id":415,"price":16.02251407129456,"id":1236}  
local.INFO: price: 16.022514071295  
local.INFO: new factor {"country_id":3,"product_id":415,"margin":0.65,"fi":0.75,"id":1239}  
local.INFO: fi 0.75  
local.INFO: margen 0.65  
local.INFO: price {"country_id":3,"product_id":415,"price":17.517948717948716,"id":1237}  
local.INFO: price: 17.517948717949
```

and this is the output from a server

```
local.INFO: array (
  'CODIGO' => 'IS2117-1103WF',
  'SKU' => 'IS2117-1103WF-GR',
  'ETIQUETAS DE RELACION' => 'Maleta, Case, ISP, Foam',
  'PROVEEDOR' => 'PELICAN',
  'DESCRIPCION - ESPAÑOL' => 'Maleta ISP, Con Foam, Equipadas con un anillo de sellado esponjoso de silicona y válvulas de descarga de presión',
  'DESCRIPCION - INGLES' => 'IS2117-1103, W/F, P127-131, GRY',
  'DESCUENTO' => 0,
  'COLOR-AB' => 'GR',
  'COLOR' => 'GREY',
  'MARCA' => 'PELICAN',
  'FOB' => 714.950000000000045474735088646411895751953125,
  'FI COSTA RICA' => 0.81999999999999995115018691649311222136020660400390625,
  'Margen COSTA RICA' => 0.6999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875,
  'FI NICARAGUA' => 0.8000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125,
  'Margen NICARAGUA' => 0.65000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625,
  'FI HONDURAS' => 0.7800000000000000266453525910037569701671600341796875,
  'Margen HONDURAS' => 0.59999999999999997779553950749686919152736663818359375,
  'Costo/Precio CR' => 1245.557491289198878803290426731109619140625,
  'Costo/Precio Nic' => 1374.90384615384618882671929895877838134765625,
  'Costo/Precio Hn' => 1527.670940170940184543724171817302703857421875,
  'PRECIO COSTA RICA' => 1245,
  'PRECIO NICARAGUA' => 1375,
  'PRECIO HONDURAS' => 1530,
  'lista-CARACTERISTICAS GENERALES-Detalle 1' => 'Temperatura Mínima:  -20° F (-29 ° C)',
  'lista-CARACTERISTICAS GENERALES-Detalle 2' => 'Temperatura Máxima:  140° F (60 ° C)',
  'lista-CARACTERISTICAS GENERALES-Detalle 3' => 'Volumen Interior:  2.89 ft³ (0.082 m³)',
  'tabla-Caracteristicas tecnicas-Dimensiones (pulgadas)' => '24x20x17',
  'tabla-Caracteristicas tecnicas-Anchura (pulgadas)' => 24,
  'tabla-Caracteristicas tecnicas-Longitud (pulgadas)' => 20,
  'tabla-Caracteristicas tecnicas-Altura (pulgadas)' => 17,
  'lista-Caracteristicas de materiales-Detalle 1' => 'Cuerpo: Polietileno',
  'lista-Caracteristicas de materiales-Detalle 2' => 'Cuerpo de Compensación: Aluminio',
  'lista-Caracteristicas de materiales-Detalle 3' => 'Cierre: Acero',
  'lista-Caracteristicas de materiales-Detalle 4' => 'Pasadores: Acero Inoxidable / Aluminio',
  'tabla-PESO-Libras ' => 26.5,
)  
local.INFO: new factor {"country_id":1,"product_id":704,"margin":0.6999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875,"fi":0.81999999999999995115018691649311222136020660400390625,"id":2110}  
local.INFO: fi 0.82  
local.INFO: margen 0.7  
local.INFO: price {"country_id":1,"product_id":704,"price":1245,"id":2110}  
local.INFO: price: 1245  
local.INFO: new factor {"country_id":2,"product_id":704,"margin":0.65000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625,"fi":0.8000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125,"id":2111}  
local.INFO: fi 0.8  
local.INFO: margen 0.65  
local.INFO: price {"country_id":2,"product_id":704,"price":1375,"id":2111}  
local.INFO: price: 1375  
local.INFO: new factor {"country_id":3,"product_id":704,"margin":0.59999999999999997779553950749686919152736663818359375,"fi":0.7800000000000000266453525910037569701671600341796875,"id":2112}  
local.INFO: fi 0.78  
local.INFO: margen 0.6  
local.INFO: price {"country_id":3,"product_id":704,"price":1530,"id":2112}  
local.INFO: price: 1530
```

The code is exactly the same on both since it's the same project, I don't know what is wrong with the server project? this is causing problems when I try to edit the product the fi and margin don't show up and I'm thinking it has to do with the differences in this output.

What could be happening?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @LucienDubois it's not so much an error, as much as when I try to edit the fi and margin show up as 0 when I know they aren't